# how to match a column in jquery for a text match and return another column from matched rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a html table which looks like below:

[image]

Is there's a way to find out dishes name according to its category.
Just based on `<td>` text? 
example: output will be 
Seafood: Scallops in Butter And Soy Sauce, Shrimps in Garlic Butter etc..
Beverage: Asahi Glass,Coke etc....
Thanks...

Comment: Yes i believe it is possible, But without showing us what you have tried it hard for us to help you any further

Comment: i think filter() method is going to help me, but not able to utilize it properly. it is looking like "jquery data table" search..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below function takes column number you want to match, the text that should be matched and if matched the returnColumn from where values must be returned.

**columnMatch** : column number you want to look the text for
**matchText** : text you want to match
**returnColumn**: column number from which you want to return text from if a match is made

```
function getMatchesFromTable(matchColumn,matchText,returnColumn)
    {
        var matchedValues = [];
        $("table tr td:nth-child("+matchColumn+")").each(function () {
              if($(this).text() == matchText){
                  matchedValues.push($(this).parent().find('td:nth-child('+returnColumn+')').text());
              }
        });

       return matchedValues;

    }
```

Example for your case you can call:

```
getMatchesFromTable(3,"Seafood",5);
```

This will return array of all elements where category is Seafood

I have tried to write a generic function to match all use cases. Still this can be more extended based on your requirements like returning multiple columns in matched rows, matching case insensitive etc. You can modify this basic function to add more capabilities to it.

Comment: trying to understand this

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var array = [];    

var headers = [];
$('table th').each(function(index, item) {
    headers[index] = $(item).html();
}); 
$('table tr').has('td').each(function() {

    var arrayItem = {};
    $('td', $(this)).each(function(index, item) {
        arrayItem[headers[index]] = $(item).html();
    });
    array.push(arrayItem);
});    
alert(JSON.stringify(array));

$(array).each(function(index, item) {
    if ($.inArray("find", item) > -1){ 
            alert('found');
    }
});
```

or you can use

```
$('table tr').has('td').each(function(index, td) {
    var tableRow = td.filter(function() {
       return $(this).text() == "foo";
    }).closest("tr");
});
```